# New Gym Contract Law in Illinois

Tags: contract-law

Previous law didnt have a contract length on it.  As of January 2019 there is a law that limits gym contracts to 1 year.  If I signed a contract before January 2019, does the new law apply to me, or do i have to wait until my current contract is up? Here is the link to the new law: [(sec 8)](http://www.ilga.gov/legislation/ilcs/ilcs3.asp?ActID=2376&ChapterID=67). I signed mine in January of 2018

Comment: Could you post a link to the statutory law? Also, when (month/year) did you sign your current contract?

Comment: You have to wait. Why would you think you may not have to wait, did the deal not go through until this year or something?

Comment: @Putvi depending on how the law is drafted it may affect existing contracts

Comment: @DaleM Not really, they aren't going to undo all old gym contracts. Also, I am from IL and it doesn't undo old contracts.

Comment: @Putvi I haven’t seen the law - if you have a link, edit the question. Government can and do alter existing contracts with legislation all the time

Comment: @DaleM They can technically alter existing contracts with new laws, but realistically no politician is going to vote to harm thousands of local businesses. The law only applies to new contracts. I will make a screen shot of it.

Comment: @Putvi it may not have happened here but it happens all the time. For example, on 17 December 2018 the payment arrangements of every construction contract in Queensland changed overnight

Comment: @DaleM Queensland? Are you Australian? Thats cool. I get what you mean, but I just meant in America that would be political suicide and you would be sued.

Comment: @Putvi legislators can’t be sued for making legislation - even bad legislation

Comment: @DaleM In America the government can be sued though and every gym owner in the state would sue the government for making their contracts invalid with no just cause. It would never hold up in court.

Comment: @Putvi the executive branch can be sued (when it allows it), the legislative and judicial branches can’t be.

Comment: @DaleM they can't be sued individually, but laws are ruled unconstitutional (which is suing the gov) every year.

Comment: @Putvi retroactive legislation is not unconstitutional. Neither, in general is retroactive executive action. For example, if the US imposed sanctions on another country that will make many, many contracts null and void.

Comment: Sanctions don't necessarily make contracts void. Just being retroactive isn't unconstitutional, but the commerce clause and equal protection would defiantly be used to sue if they made gym contracts void just because they wanted to. A sanction is meant to punish and normally making a law retro active address some safety concern.

Answer (score 1):

The version of the statute at http://www.ilga.gov/legislation/ilcs/ilcs3.asp?ActID=2376&ChapterID=67 does not indicate an effective date, nor does it mention retroactivity. It is **probably** only applicable to contracts signed or renewed after its effective date, whatever that may be, because retroactive application is usually mentioned explicitly, but one cannot be sure. Civil Laws are made retroactive quite commonly, and are not void or unconstitutional thereby, although the Contract Clause of the Federal constitution does limit retroactive laws to some extent.

Comment: It lists when it is relevant in the law. As I said, it applies to contracts signed this year.

Answer (score 0):

If you signed up in 2018 it does not apply. It only applies to new contracts.

Comment: source please. A mere assertion without a quote or a link to the new law is of limited value, particularly when your comments imply you haven't actually read the new law.

Comment: I tried to edit the question as I was asked to do, to include a picture of the relevant part of the law.

Comment: @DavidSiegel, I didn't read the whole thing, but I read the section he asked about.

Comment: It is better to include a text quote, or a link. An image in infexible, and usually not as helpful. It is also more trouble to upload.

Comment: I get you, I just wanted to highlight the relevant part.

Comment: Can you give the section and paragraph ID which indicates the applicable date?

Comment: @DavidSiegel, Normally, IL laws will list the date they are effective at the bottom, or within the law. Where it says "(Source: P.A. 100-658, eff. 1-1-19.)", the eff. stands for effective.